# Rapahel set.splice() issue

Tags: set, raphael, splice

The following code throws an error "s.splice is not a function":

```
    var s = this.paper.set();
    s.push(this.paper.rect(10,10,100,100));
    s.push(this.paper.rect(10,10,100,100));
    s.splice(0,1);
```

`s.clear` also throws a similar eror.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks much.

Comment: After additional research and experimentation, I found I could reach into the set and manipulate its `items` property which is a regular JS array holding all the elements in the set.  Not an ideal or satisfactory solution though.  Plus it comes with the burden of having to update the set's `length` property whenever I make modifications to `items` that results in a change in array length.  Like I said, not pretty.

Comment: 1.5.2 does not appear to have a splice method: http://jsfiddle.net/2YsSy/3/ , but 2 does: http://jsfiddle.net/2YsSy/4/

Comment: @oli Thanks! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it as my accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. Are you sure `this.paper` really points to the raphael paper? try with `console.log(this.paper)` and see if it's a Raphael instance.

This works for me:

```
var paper = Raphael("paper", 300, 300); 
var s = paper.set();
    s.push(paper.rect(10,10,100,100));
    s.push(paper.rect(10,10,100,100));
    s.splice(0,1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that but got the same error.  I'm using Raphael 1.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you're using 1.5.2, which does not appear to have a splice method: http://jsfiddle.net/2YsSy/3/

2 however does: http://jsfiddle.net/2YsSy/4/